# How to salt whole potatoes before roasting or cooking in the microwave?

Tags: potatoes

Is there a way to salt a whole potato before microwaving or baking it, I was thinking of soaking it in salty water but I doubt that would work, I need it to be seasoned on the inside not just the skin.

Comment: What are you after here? Why do you "need" it to be seasoned on the inside? What is to gain from this?

Comment: Since it is pretty much already water saturated you will not get much past the skin

Comment: @CosCallis For the same reason I season everything, to be tastier

Comment: @AhmadHani, what is the basis for believing that "If you can season the potato beforehand" it will be "tastier"?

Comment: @CosCallis It is not necessarily the before hand part but having the salt uniformly distributed is what I am after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot season a whole potato from the outside when baking or microwaving, the flavor may penetrate a small amount but most of the potato will be unseasoned. Boiling potatoes in salty water will give you a better result, however the skin of a whole potato will still block much of the flavor.

The only way I could think of to salt the inside of a whole potato would be so inject a salt solution into it with a syringe, which seems excessive. You'd probably be better off simply cutting the potato open after it's cooked and seasoning it then.